# Sql Azure Data Sync Agent invalid key error message

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Windows 8 64 bit 
DAta sync agente ver. 4.0.89.0

Error message  , I tried reinstall 3 times data sync and 4 tiems new agent and new key also.

No prosy or internet fire wall one no other fire wall software also.

Please enter a valid agent key to proceed. The key must be generated from SQL DAta Sync web portal

agent key 16f25226-2a20-49c3-acfc-062057c42b41:gWpFO0NHm4Xq9bw7fLzo8YS49iSowEDQToYpbMCKqFk=

id:LocalAgentUX_Info, rId:, sId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, traceLevel:Warning, version:4.0.0.0, methodName:AgentModel_AgentStatusChanged, message:Agent UI stopped polling for the latest status from Microsoft SQL Data Sync Windows service due to errors. Please address any errors displayed in the UI and then restart Microsoft SQL Data Sync Windows service on your machine and Agent UI to resume polling.

Comment: Please edit your question with the available formatting options and make sure you actually ask a 'question'. I can't understand head nor tails of it now.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common error. You have to change your system's date to match azure server's time.

Go to the Azure Website and check the location of the server, than set your system's date and time to the same location's time zone.

This worked fine for me,

Comment: This worked for me as well. The server time wasn't syncing correctly. I changed from time.windows.com to one of the NIST servers and forced a sync. Then the key was accepted.

Comment: Thanks for that. Saved our bacon ;-) Our server was 6 minutes out for some reason. Changed time and all good.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no time difference it's also worth checking that the password doesn't contain any special chars like quotes ‘ and double quotes “

Browser auto-generated passwords might include that without you realising it.