# Please enter a valid agent key to proceed. The key must be generated from SQL Data sync web portal"

Tags: azure-sql-database

While adding generated key from Azure to Data sync Agent, it is showing "Please enter a valid agent key to proceed. The key must be generated from SQL Data sync web portal".

I configured Azure data sync earlier on MS SQL 2008 R2 but I didn't face this issue, but while now configuring with MS SQL 2008 R2 server I'm facing this issue

Is there issues with SQL server 2008 R2? Please let me know.

Comment: this seems similar:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593671/sql-azure-data-sync-agent-invalid-key-error-mesage

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your system's date and Azure server time are the same. You can do this by checking the location of the server and setting your system's date and time to the same one.

This worked for a few people, let me know if this resolves the issue.